# TestComplete object not found errors

Tags: testcomplete

I am new to TestComplete.

I watched a couple of videos they have but when I tried the same thing it gives me error about not finding the objects. All I did was recorded going to a web app and logging into it.

Has anyone faced this kind of problem and if so any pointers to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic solution to such situations, other than investigating the situation to find out why the expected recognition criteria do not match the actual ones.
There is a recording of a recent webinar about Name Mapping - it describes some situations when objects are not found, and gives some good advices on the possible solutions:
http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/screencasts/reliable-tests-for-dynamic-objects/

Anyway, you will need to make some investigations to determine the root cause of the situation before you can try applying some suggestions.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The help system of TestComplete 8 contains a great topic describing all possible causes of the '*Object not found*' issue and suggesting ways for debugging and solving them: [Handling the 'Object Not Found' Errors](http://support.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/12169/).

Answer (score 0):

Use object browser to highlight any object. You can also script to check the Exists property before performing any action.

For objects which I am not sure would exists, I usually user Wait with timeout and then check the Exists property to avoid Object not found error.